# How to wrap text within multiline react native textInput

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput

I am trying to implement a multiline text input in react native, but when user types the text doesn't get wrapped but gets written horizontally on the same line,

the code for my text input is as follows

```
<View style={[styles.container, props.containerStyles]}>
  <TextInput 
    style={styles.placeholderStyle} 
    placeholder={"Placeholder text"}
    value={this.state.reviewBody}
    onChangeText={body => this.setState({ reviewBody: body })}
    numberOfLines={5}
    textAlignVertical={"top"}
    textBreakStrategy={"highQuality"}
    underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
    autoCorrect
  />
</View>
```

and the styles are,

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#f4f4f4",
    width: WIDTH - 40,
    maxWidth: WIDTH - 40,
    minWidth: WIDTH - 40,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  placeholderStyle: {
    fontSize: 11,
    padding: 0,
    flex: 1,
    width: WIDTH - 40,
    maxWidth: WIDTH - 40,
    minWidth: WIDTH - 40,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    overflow: "scroll"
  },
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `TextInput` component, use props `multiline={true}`, this should solve your issue. Also if you want to control the text alignment behavior, you can use `textAlignVertical` props.
Find more details in this link - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#multiline

Comment: By the way, once I was asked not only to enable "wrap", but also to make `enter` accepts the text in a multiline TextInput (normal behavior: `enter` adds a new line). It took some time to get this done; finally, I got this property `blurOnSubmit`, when set to true (in a multiline TextInput) means that pressing return will trigger the onSubmitEditing. [reference](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#bluronsubmit).

Answer (score 0):

### 2023 Update

I was having a problem where I could not use `multiline={true}` because it messes with my `KeyboardAvoidingView` logic ([known bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16826)). My workaround was to have a fixed height and set `textAlign: 'justify'` to the style prop of my TextInputs. The words appear to wrap now.